# Find the next three lines and explain what the pattern is

Tags: number-sequence

```
                           345
                         131415
                      111311141115              
                     311331143115 
                      1321232114132115
                1113121112131221141113122115
```

I have tried everything and still cannot figure this out.

Comment: There are quite a few questions with this pattern around here.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Puzzling. I suggest you to take the tour to know how this works and also win badges with it.

Comment: I take it from the way you ask the question that the puzzle isn't one you've made up; you should say where you got it from.

Comment: this must be one of the most known sequence in the universe.

Comment: Yes indeed. Though the *question* is different, even though the *answer* is the same. What's the etiquette for this?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Sadly I have no idea.

Comment: The idea is same. In number sequences, that matters. Probably will be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I understand that its a duplicate in terms of it being the same idea, however I need to get the next three lines for THIS problem. Its an extra credit for school so I did not make this one up.

Comment: @antjodi You got the idea, proceed similarly. you would get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems similar to another question. Basically,

> Each line is just a read-out of the preceding line. E.g. 345 becomes one 3, one 4, one 5 (131415), which in turn becomes one 1, one 3, one 1, one 4, etc.

Comment: Yup. We should probably mark this as a duplicate rather than giving answers, though :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: whoops.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> .[Look and say sequence..](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence)